# Please remove blacklisted tags from 'recommended' tag badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

We've blacklisted the tag, preventing getting the badge for [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) but if the tag is still your closest tag to receiving a badge the system will still suggest it as the recommended.

[image: Tag Badge suggest page]

Can this please be adjusted to not recommend tags that we have blacklisted, since these are now impossible to acquire?

Comment: I think this is a bug in the progress system and you should tag it as such

Comment: The blacklist system is a separated entity of the other systems, they don't share information. (And blacklists are regex-based=

Comment: @braiam I don't really care about the technical implementation or how they have to fix it.

Comment: You may not, but if you want it to be implemented the developer needs to know what the heck is going on, [as they may sometimes don't even remember how stuff works](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4951731#4951731)

Comment: If a tag is so bad that it was blacklisted, what's the benefit of keeping it? And if the existing questions are worth keeping, why is the tag blacklisted? Removing the tag sounds like the way to go here rather than complicating the progress tracker.

Comment: @Adam some id request questions and answers were good quality ones netting the posters a good deal of rep and ideally we would have wanted all I'd request to be like that. however the tag was blacklisted because too many users don't put in any effort into their I'd request questions so as apart of the process to make them off-topic the tag was black listed and low quality questions were deleted while high quality ones where kept and historically locked, preserving some of the hard work people put into them

Comment: also with the blacklisting we are able to prevent people from using it and presenting them with a message leading them to the meta discussion on the topic showing why we no longer accept them. not that it makes any difference to some who saw it was blacklisted and still posted their question apologising for not using the right tags because of the black list

Comment: @Adam I can't imagine that having a tag recommended to users which is impossible to obtain was a design decision, so why is the bug tag removed?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade Feature request to change existing behavior seems enough to me. There's several badges that are impossible to obtain (eg beta). Tag badges aren't particular special in that sense. If you feel strongly, you're free to revert my edit, but I do feel this is more of a feature change than a bug report.